# Error from @Generated when running Jacoco report

Tags: android, dagger-2, jacoco

I am trying to run a Jacoco report from Android Studio. When doing so, the ViewModule and UserModule from the Dagger2 generated class gives errors stating

> error: cannot find symbol
>   @Generated(
>    ^
>     symbol: class Generated
>
> error: package javax.annotation.processing does not exist

I am not sure as to why Dagger is not compiling or being ignored.

My Gradle task to run the Jacoco report is and I am using version 0.8.5

```
task testDebugUnitTestCoverage(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ['testDevelopmentDebugUnitTest', 'connectedDevelopmentDebugAndroidTest']) {
    group = "Reporting"
    description = "Generates aggregate report for unit tests and instrumentation tests"

    reports {
        html.enabled = true
        xml.enabled = true
    }

    def excludes = [
            '**/R.class',
            '**/R$*.class',
            '**/BuildConfig.*',
            '**/*Activity*.*',
            '**/Manifest*.*',
            '**/*Test*.*',
            'android/**/*.*',
            'androidx/**/*.*',
            'io/realm/**/*.*',
            '**/*InjectAdapter*.*',
            '**/*StaticInjection*.*',
            '**/*ModuleAdapter*.*'
    ]

    // generated classes
    classDirectories.from = fileTree(
            dir: "$buildDir/intermediates/classes/debug",
            excludes: excludes
    ) + fileTree(
            dir: "$buildDir/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug",
            excludes: excludes
    )

    // sources
    sourceDirectories.from = files([
            android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs,
            "src/main/kotlin"
    ])

    executionData.setFrom(fileTree(dir: "$project.buildDir", includes: [
            "jacoco/testDevelopmentDebugUnitTest.exec",
            "outputs/code_coverage/developmentDebugAndroidTest/connected/*coverage.ec"
    ]))
```